# Best way to extract code from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Pow and Rails 4 on OS X.

I have a `SearchController` which takes a query and searches for it on various backend services (YouTube, SoundCloud, Last.fm, etc).

I want to take these backends and put inside their own files/classes, to keep the code clean and make it easy to add more backends.

So my question is: where should I put these files? I have tried to make a folder called `backend`, containing all files, and put it inside `app/controller` and `app/models`. I then put `require 'backend/lastfm.rb'` in my controller and it works. But it's only loaded once, so I have to `touch tmp/restart.txt` every time I make a change. Not ideal!

Same issue when putting it into `lib`, even when I try to use eager loading.

So where can I put this folder so I can use the code from my `SearchController` and have it reload the files at every request (in development mode)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For autoload your folders you should add paths to `application.rb`:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/backend/*)
end
```

Now you `backend` folder autoload, and you do not need `require`s you files.

Comment: Thanks. Putting it there worked much better than in the lib folder.

Comment: my pleasure, you choose right way for extracting huge controllers, just add autoload path.